# Determine repeating numbers in a string in R

Tags: r, regex, string, detect

I am trying to identify column values in a data frame that have repeating number sequence.
For instance

```
> df
   ColA
1 66046
2 73947
3 67456
4 67217
5 66861
6 67658
```

I want to return 66046, 66861 as 6 appears in succession.
I have tried the following...

```
df %>% filter(str_detect(as.String(df[1]), "[66]"))  #with and without the squared brackets.
df[unlist(gregexpr("[6]{2}[[:digit:]]", df[1])), ][1]
```

Obvious to say, this doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(ColA, "(\\d)\\1"))
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/UrGyjy/1)

| NODE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\d` | digits (0-9) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `\1` | what was matched by capture \1 |

Answer (score 3):

We can specify the count with

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(ColA, "6{2,}"))
```

-output

```
#   ColA
#1 66046
#5 66861
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c(66046L, 73947L, 67456L, 67217L, 66861L, 
67658L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.. That worked.. 

Is there a way I could retrieve values where any of the numbers repeat in succession.. Not just 6.. I tried [[:digits:]] in place of 6 but that returns everything.

Comment: ColA
1 66006
2 67003
3 67226
4 73933

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but here's a solution in `base R`:

```
df[which(grepl("(\\d)\\1", df$ColA)),]
```